# Populate multiple comboboxes based on name and for loop, VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, for-loop, combobox

I am currently working in visual studio express 2013 with vb.net. I have 5 combo boxes that all have the same items that needed to be added into them. The names of the combobox are CBWeekday1, Cbweekday2,....CBweekday5. I want to use a loop statement to fill the boxes with the same data rather than have to use a line for every item for every combobox. However, I am receiving an error code and I think I have this set up wrong.

```
   Dim n As Integer = 1
    For n = 1 To 5
        Dim cb = DirectCast(Me.Controls("CBWeekday" & n &), ComboBox)
        ComboBox.Items.add("Monday")
        ComboBox.Items.add("Tuesday")
        ComboBox.Items.add("Wednesday")
        ComboBox.Items.add("Thursday")
        ComboBox.Items.add("Friday")
    Next
```

Comment: You should tell us what the error is - or errors are, as I see at least 2 things wrong with the code. In the `Me.Controls("CbWeekday" & n &)` line the second `&` is unnecesary  unles you're going to concat something else. Also, you declared a variable named `cb` but you're using directly `ComboBox` instead of your variable.

Comment: @JoshPart  The error was an error in the reference but I made your changes and it works now. I will upload the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is this:

```
    Dim n As Integer = 1
    For n = 1 To 5
        Dim cb = DirectCast(Me.Controls("CBWeekday" & n), ComboBox)
        cb.Items.Add("Monday")
        cb.Items.Add("Tuesday")
        cb.Items.Add("Wednesday")
        cb.Items.Add("Thursday")
        cb.Items.Add("Friday")
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more efficient for simple ones:

```
Private weekdays As String() = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
                               "Thursday", "Friday"}
...
' if you know the name of the control. use it:
cbWeekday.Items.AddRange(weekdays)
```

---

For *five* cbos (I missed that part at first):

```
' module level declaration
Private DayNames As String() = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
                               "Thursday", "Friday"}
Private weekdays As List(Of String)

Private Sub Form_Load(...
    Dim cboWkDays As ComboBox() = {cbWkDay1, cbWkDay2}

    weekdays = New List(of String)(DayNames)
    For Each cbo As ComboBox In cboWkDays
        cbo.DataSource = weekdays
    Next
```

Personally, I'd do without the `cboWkDays` array and just set them directly (but the title asks for a loop).  The efficiency with 5 of them is that there is *one* copy of day names.  Rather than copying them to `Items` use the `List(of String)` as a datasource.

If you wanted to be culture agnostic, get the day names like this:

```
    Dim cult As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture  

    weekdays = cult.DateTimeFormat.DayNames().ToList()
    weekdays.RemoveAt(6)      ' sat
    weekdays.RemoveAt(0)      ' sunday
```

Comment: Yes it is more efficient, I shall update my code and answer as well.